# Run specific function before executing any code in the view

Tags: django, django-views

I haven't worked too much with Django. Let's say I have three views. The url patterns that these views are mapped to all start with string Y.

Suppose I want to run specific function X before running code that the views contain.
Is there a way to run function X by adding it somewhere only once instead of adding the function call to to the beginning of each of these views separately? Would [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/) be the recommended way to do this?

EDIT:
I went now with a decorator, so decorating all my three functions. But I feels the solution is not optimal because I needed to use the decorator in multiple places. 3 is not a problem but if there would be more functions that need to be decorated, it's starts to be more difficult to maintain (or refactor) later on.

I will test the other suggested solutions and report the results.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple wrapper do the trick? And wrap your functional view with it `@wrapper`, that's how [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) works.

Comment: Are you using Django Class-Based views? If so, override the [**`dispatch()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method. If you are using functional-based view, you can call whatever function you want from thereby calling it

Comment: We'll need more information about the full requirements of this. Middleware might be correct, but so might a decorator as filfilt mentioned. And then there's also the possibility that overriding `dispatch` could be the right move as well.